# Electron Desktop Capturer audio not working on Windows

Tags: typescript, windows, electron, mediastream, desktopcapturer

I can get the `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);` to work with audio set to false, but as soon as I add audio as follows:

```
constraints.audio = {
                mandatory: {
                    chromeMediaSource: 'desktop'
                }
            }
```

then I get a `DOMexception`: Audio could not be started

Is there a solution to capture the audio along with the video. All issues I found so far states that this solution works on Windows but not Ubuntu, but I find that this does not work on Windows as well

Comment: I tested a bit more and found that it does not work with usb headsets as selected audio output. I do require it to work with usb devices as well